# Создать свой Task.Run

Tags: c#, асинхронность, lambda, task

Каким образом в c# можно сделать async получив значение во внешний метод из лямбды?

Вот тестовый пример (он нерабочий):

```
    public async Task<MyOtherClass> Test(MyClass data)
    {
        return Task.Run<MyOtherClass>(() => {

            MyOtherClass result = null;
            bool endFlag = false;

            protocol.Invoke((MyOtherClass response) => // это async
            {
                endFlag = true;
                result = response;
            }, "uri/to/my/rpc", data);

            for (;;) // а это уже await
            {
                Thread.Sleep(200);
                if (endFlag)
                    break;
            }

            return result;

        });
    }
```

Задача функции Test - вытащить значение **`response`** из лямбды, и вернуть его, причём, сделать это надо асинхронно, к циклу **`for(;;)`** хотелось бы перйти только когда потребуется **`await`**. Подскажите, что нужно сделать, и почему этот код студия ругает?

[image: Ошибка в IDE]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вероятно, вам надо что то вроде

```
public Task<MyOtherClass> Test(MyClass data)
{
    return Task.Run<MyOtherClass>(async () =>
    {

        MyOtherClass result = null;
        bool endFlag = false;

        protocol.Invoke((MyOtherClass response) => // это async
        {
            endFlag = true;
            result = response;
        }, "uri/to/my/rpc", data);

        for (; ; ) // а это уже await
        {
            await Task.Delay(200);
            if (endFlag)
                break;
        }

        return result;

    });
}
```

Но если вызов `protocol.Invoke` не блокирующий, то внутренний таск нам не нужен, у нас же уже асинхронный код.

```
public async Task<MyOtherClass> Test(MyClass data)
{
    MyOtherClass result = null;
    bool endFlag = false;

    protocol.Invoke((MyOtherClass response) => // это async
    {           
        result = response;
        endFlag = true; // И лучше бы флагать о конце операции в конце метода, чтобы не возникло проблем с race condition
    }, "uri/to/my/rpc", data);

    for (; ; ) // а это уже await
    {
        await Task.Delay(200);
        if (endFlag)
            break;
    }

    return result;
}
```

а вот уже совсем короткий вариант, что делает по сути то же самое

```
public Task<MyOtherClass> Test(MyClass data)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<MyOtherClass>(); 
    protocol.Invoke((MyOtherClass response) => // это async
    {       
        tcs.SetResult(response);
    }, "uri/to/my/rpc", data);  
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @test123 обратите внимание на последний вариант, вам понравится :)